# ORACLE SQL group based on values in a reference table

Tags: sql, oracle, datatables, reference, rank

Customer table and Acct tables has global scope, they share and increment this value

Below is customer table, SEQ NO 1 is beginning of customer data, SEQ_NO 238 is beginning of another customer data

[image]

Another is account table, all accounts with their SEQ_NOs inside a boundary of customer get same group (I want to group those accounts to the same customer, so that I can use listAgg to concatenate account id.), for example, below from SEQ_NO 2 and NO 224 (inclusive) should be assigned to the same group.

[image]

Is there a SQL way to do that, The worst case I was thinking is to define oracle type, and using function do that.

Any help is appreciate.

Comment: In technical fields, such as computing and programming, you must use precise language. To "listagg" you must **group** things together, not "rank" them. "Ranking", like "grouping", is a technical term in SQL, with a very precise meaning, different from what you are talking about. I will edit your post to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to assign rows in the account table to **groups**, one per customer, so that you can then aggregate based on these groups.

So, the question is how to identify to which customer each account belongs, based on the sequence boundaries given in the first table ("customer") and the specific account numbers in the second table ("account").

This can be done in plain SQL, and relatively easily. You need a join between the accounts table and a subquery based on the customers table. The subquery must show the first and the last sequence number allocated to each client; to do that, you can use the `lead` analytic function. A bit of care must be taken regarding the last customer, for whom there is no upper limit for the sequence numbers.

You didn't provide test data in a usable format, so I created sample data in the `with` clause below (which is not part of the query - it's just there as a placeholder for test data).

```
with
  customer (cust_id, seq_no) as (
    select 101,  1 from dual union all
    select 102, 34 from dual union all
    select 200, 58 from dual union all
    select 130, 90 from dual
  )
, account (acct_id, seq_no) as (
    select 1003,  3 from dual union all
    select 1005, 11 from dual union all
    select 1007, 33 from dual union all
    select 1008, 60 from dual union all
    select 1103, 77 from dual union all
    select 1140, 92 from dual union all
    select 1145, 99 from dual
  )
select c.cust_id, 
       listagg(a.acct_id, ',') within group (order by a.acct_id) as acct_list
from   (
         select cust_id, seq_no as lower_no,
                lead(seq_no) over (order by seq_no) - 1 as upper_no
         from   customer
       ) c
       left outer join account a
       on a.seq_no between c.lower_no and nvl(c.upper_no, a.seq_no)
group  by c.cust_id
order  by c.cust_id
;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
CUST_ID  ACCT_LIST           
-------  --------------------
    101  1003,1005,1007      
    102                     
    130  1140,1145           
    200  1008,1103
```